# Change permissions on a file using a sheet and Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with multiple rows which list a name, email, filename, fileID, fileURL, and a list of permissions. I want my scrip to change the permissions on each file as it loops through the a foreach loop on the data. I can't seem to get the file id to be carried forward into the loop.

```
function shareFile() {
  const sheet = SS.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const fileID = sheet.getRange(2, 4).getValue();
  const fileToShare = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
  const permissionsData = sheet.getRange('A2:F').getValues();
  permissionsData.forEach(row => {
    if (row[5] === "Viewer") {
      fileToShare.addViewer(row[1]);
    } else if (row[5] === "Commentor") {
      fileToShare.addCommenter(row[1]);
    } else if (row[5] === "Editor") {
      fileToShare.addEditor(row[1]);
    } else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Permissions must be set to "Viewer", "Commentor", or "Editor". Please check your input. Thank you');
    }
  })
}
```

What do I change here to get the correct file ID for each row to change permissions based on column F?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your sample Spreadsheet of your provided image, in your script, `const permissionsData = sheet.getRange('A2:F').getValues();` includes the file ID. I thought that this can be used.
- In your sample Spreadsheet, I thought that it might be required to consider the case that columns "A" to "E" have no values while column "F" has the values.

If these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function shareFile() {
  const SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Please set your Spreadsheet.

  const sheet = SS.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const permissionsData = sheet.getRange('B2:F' + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(([b, , d, , f]) => b && d && f);
  permissionsData.forEach(([email, , fileId, , permission]) => {
    let fileToShare;
    try {
      fileToShare = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("No file ID.");
      return;
    }
    if (permission === "Viewer") {
      fileToShare.addViewer(email);
    } else if (permission === "Commentor") {
      fileToShare.addCommenter(email);
    } else if (permission === "Editor") {
      fileToShare.addEditor(email);
    } else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Permissions must be set to "Viewer", "Commentor", or "Editor". Please check your input. Thank you');
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from "Sheet1" by filtering the rows. And, the permission of column "F" is added to the files of file IDs of column "D" using the email of column "B".

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

```
function shareFile() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getRange('A2:F' + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    let file = DriveApp.getFileById(r[3]);
    if (r[5] === "Viewer") {
      file.addViewer(r[1]);
    } else if (r[5] === "Commentor") {
      file.addCommenter(r[1]);
    } else if (r[5] === "Editor") {
      file.addEditor(r[1]);
    } else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Permissions must be set to "Viewer", "Commentor", or "Editor". Please check your input. Thank you');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion @cooper. when I log permissionsdata it doesn't seem to filter the data, I get [ [ 'Viewer',
    '',
    'Dirk Johnson',
    'twelch@lgsd.us',
    'School Calendar Template - Dirk Johnson',
    '16_S9zHiT0yEjeS88Kb44h8u1GqT8LO7RjVInK5aRTCY' ], when I expect to just get permisisons,email,fileID. Is that correct?

Comment: @tanaike I have tried this approach and it makes sense, and when I log vs I do get all the data, but I don't think that it is actually getting the filebyid, as it does not change the permissions as in this error: Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp. So I guess the method of getting the ID using the row[] is not working, not sure why not.